# Undo change, plus msgbox in ActiveSheet If range in another worksheet becomes less than cell below

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In `("Menu")` range `C15:C25` I'm entering values that are reflected in worksheet `("Pack Plan")` range `B5:P5` with some calculations, then in `("Pack Plan")` Range `B6:P6` I have other calculated values. I need a code that will undo any change in `("Menu")` range `C15:C25` and `MsgBox "Adjust Pack Plan"` If that change caused the value of any cell in `("Pack Plan")` range `B5:P5` to be less than the value of the cell right below. Currently I have 15 IF's to execute this. I need a single IF argument which will allow for more conditions to be added without having to duplicate them for each IF.
`("Menu")` is the active sheet.

In answers to similar questions I didn't see anything that worked.

Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If (Target.Column = 5) Then

'I'm trying to consolidate the following IF arguments into 2 set's of IF code instead of having IF's for each cell in range.
'First these two If's:

            If Worksheets("Crème").Range("C11").Value > Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("B5").Value Then
                MsgBox "Missing Ingredient!"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Crème").Range("C12").Value > Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("I5").Value Then
                MsgBox "Missing Ingredient!"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            
'Then the following 15 IF's:

            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("B5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("B6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("C5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("C6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("D5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("D6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("E5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("E6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("F5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("F6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("G5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("G6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("H5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("H6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("I5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("I6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("J5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("J6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("K5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("K6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("L5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("L6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("M5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("M6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("N5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("N6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("O5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("O6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("P5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("P6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
        End If
        
' code to be consolidated ends here

        If (Target.Column = 3) Then
            If (Target.Offset(0, 2)) <> "" Then
                Application.Undo
                MsgBox "Clear Batch Size First", vbExclamation, "RESTRICTED"
            End If
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to name your ranges before you code. Even if you don't:

```
Dim oTest as Range

For Each oTest in Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("B5:P5").Cells
    If oTest.Value2 < oTest.Offset(1,0).Value2 Then
        ...
        Exit For ' So you don't repeat the message box needlessly
    End If
Next oTest

Set oTest=Nothing
```

With named ranges (e.g. "CalculatedValues" for your "Pack Plan" row 5), your code simplifies to:

```
Dim oTest as Range

For Each oTest in [CalculatedValues].Cells
    If ...
    ...
    End If
Next oTest
Set oTest=Nothing
```

Similar concept for your "missing ingredient" tests.